# Sum Function in R won't return 0

Tags: r

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure this one. Lets say I have the following numeric vector:

```
mynumbers <- c(-3.6, -3.6, -2.6 , 4.4 , 5.4)
```

Why does the `sum(mynumbers)` return `-1.136868e-13` and not 0? Unless I am misunderstanding the sum function in R, shouldn't the numbers add up to 0?

Comment: It does. See for example [Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: Although this is a dupe, this does not deserves downvotes as no average R user should know these type of things. After all, we are just mathematicians who can't program...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Neither a downvoter nor a mathematician.

Comment: @Pascal me too. It's just another name for a statistician. Old joke, nvm.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Even not statistician :) Anyway, I agree with your comment.